# Импорт статических файлов react

Tags: reactjs, svg, typescript

Есть проект на `ts`, создал используя `cra`. Использую для стилей библиотеку `vanilla-extract` и по [инструкции](https://sandroroth.com/blog/vanilla-extract-cra) добавил `craco` с использованием `@vanilla-extract/webpack-plugin`.
Встала задача импортировать статические файлы (пока что svg и jpg). Перепробовал разные методы описанные [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript), [тут](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-svg-icon-components/#alternative-react-svg-loader:%7E:text=Webpack%20package%20for-,SVGR,-%3A) и на других ресурсах.
Самые очевидные варианты:

```
import image from './img/CloseIcon.svg';
import image1 from './img/first.jpg';
```

Дают ошибку того, что это не ts модули: `Не удается найти модуль "./img/first.jpg" или связанные с ним объявления типов.`
Варианты с использованием require(...) - аналогично.

Единственное решение которое я смог найти следующее:
в `src` создал папку `types` с файлом `custom.d.ts` содержимое следующее:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import * as React from 'react';

    export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
        React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }
    >;

    const src: string;
    export default src;
}

declare module '*.jpg' {
    const src: string;
    export default src;
}
```

В файл `tsconfig.json` добавил следующее: `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"]`
Теперь импорт изображений работает:

```
import image from './img/CloseIcon.svg'; //работает
const image1 = require('./img/first.jpg') as string; //работает
const image2: string = require('./img/CloseIcon.svg').default; //работает
import image3 from './img/first.jpg'; //работает
const image4: string = require('./img/first.jpg').default; //не работает
```

Это не сильно критично, хотя непонятно почему последняя запись не работает, т.е. файл не загружается.

Вопрос в том как правильно нужно подключать аналогичные статические файлы без написания собственных типов

Comment: Зачем вы пытаетесь картинку(jpg) импортировать в проект. Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Чтобы вывести её в компоненте, так как обычный путь до картинки не срабатывает без этих костылей

Comment: Неужели отрисованный тег `<img src='file.jpg'>` не подтягивает картинку сервера и вы хотите ее положить прям в код? Если это так, то попробуйте импортировать ее в тип данных Blob. Blob потом можно подставить в img как изображение. Почитайте [про Blob](https://learn.javascript.ru/blob)

Comment: Вроде всё правильно подключено - чем не устраивает-то?

Comment: @SwaD, например, добавление хэша к файлу для корректного кэширования. Или вообще для конвертирования картинок в nextjs. И ещё куча вариантов. Так у него и будет `import smth from "smth.jpg"; ... <img src={smth} />`. Нафига тут вообще blob???

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. Кто-то может это объяснить? Мне помогло.
Использовал styled-components шаблон react-ts. Была ошибка при импорте img - "Не удается найти модуль "blablabla.jpg" или связанные с ним объявления типов."
Хотел добавить в backgroung-image

Comment: разве это ответ на вопрос?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, по-моему тоже на ответ не похоже, но фраза "Мне помогло" смущает...